# How can I rotate through multiple classes indefinitley?

Tags: jquery, class, rotation

I am trying to create a rotating box effect using Jquery. I've made 8 div boxes with a total of 8 classes. 4 of the classes are in a active state and 4 of them are in non active states. The difference between the active and non active classes is the width, height and absolute position coordinates.

So basically I have 4 larger boxes and 4 smaller boxes, and I want the contents of these boxes to  automatic alternate from active (larger boxes) to non active (smaller boxes).

To see the rotating effect, please visit jsfiddle link 1:http://jsfiddle.net/gnswK/
I want the animation to run like this, but without a click trigger. I need this to auto-rotation or cycle through classes.

```
  jQuery.fn.rotateClasses = function(classes, interval, max) {
    var currentRotation = 0;
    var timer = null;
    var rotateFn = (function() {
        var currentClass = currentRotation % classes.length;
        var previousClass = currentClass - 1;
        if(previousClass == -1) previousClass = classes.length - 1;
        this.addClass(classes[currentClass]).removeClass(classes[previousClass]);
        currentRotation += 1;
        if(max > 0 && currentRotation >= max) clearInterval(timer);
    })();
    timer = setInterval(rotateFn, interval);
    return this;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rotator').rotateClasses(["active", "active2", "active3", "active4", "non-active-1", "non-active-2", "non-active-3", "non-active-4"], 1000, 0)
});
```

please take a look at my attempt to re-script the animation and add an auto rotation. jsfiddle link 2: http://jsfiddle.net/gnswK/2/

Comment: +1 for the Talking Heads reference

Comment: Do you plan on doing this with more than 8 boxes in the future? I definitely would have went about this a different way.. acting upon the indexes of the `<div>` boxes rather than uniquely identifying them. If you don't mind, I'm going to mess with your fiddle.

Comment: I want to point out a small issue with the code that you have written.. You need to add and remove class of the elements in question, and `this` points to `#rotator` .. So you need to find the elements with that class first.. You can start from here http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gnswK/3/

Comment: No i dont plan on using 8 boxes in the future but if you know of an easier way please show me.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I'm not understanding exacly what you mean. Should I use #block-1 instead of #rotator? please advise. Thank you for your help Sushanth and DevishOne

Comment: @ShawnPhillips.. What I mean was .. You were trying to add and remove class to the Main selector that was passed in `$('#rotator')` .. But in realty those logic has to be applied to the blocks inside them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is very nice, but the implementation required several adjustments.

First, the `rotateFn` transferred to `setInterval` was not a function, but whatever was returned from the first function call (since you used `(function(){...})()`).

Second, the interval handler was not bound to the appropriate object. In jQuery you can use `rotateFn.bind($(this))` in order to bind the desired scope to the handler.

Third, you wanted to rotate the classes, not set the same class to all. Therefore, you need to assign a class to each `div` based on its index and the current cycle.

The result:

```
jQuery.fn.rotateClasses = function(classes, interval, max) {
    var currentRotation = 1;
    var timer = null;
    var rotateFn = function() {
        var len = classes.length;
        var cycle = currentRotation++ % len;
        this.find('> div').each(function(id,div){
            $(div).removeClass().addClass(classes[(cycle+id)%len]);
        });

        if(max > 0 && currentRotation > max) clearInterval(timer);
    };

    timer = setInterval(rotateFn.bind($(this)), interval);

    return this;
};


$('#rotator').rotateClasses(["active", "active2", "active3", "active4", "non-active-1", "non-active-2", "non-active-3", "non-active-4"], 1000, 20);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/fnBgu/).

By the way, your original fiddle's class assignment order was different  and did not follow any particular rotation logic. You can adjust the handler if you want the order to be different.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It works exactly how I wanted it! Also thanks for explaining! Now I will just add a pause on hover effect and I will be on my way.